# Shrinking circle on Zeta zeroes. $\zeta(s + \Delta r e^{i \theta})$ when $\zeta(s) = 0$ and $\Delta r \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I have a very simple question about the Riemann Hypothesis that's probably quite obvious to somebody with more experience in complex analysis.  I was having trouble with the same type of problem in my functional analysis book, as well.

Why does the truth of

$$ \frac{\zeta(s + \Delta r e ^{i\theta})}{||\zeta(s + \Delta r e ^{i\theta})||} = -\frac{\zeta(s - \Delta r e ^{i\theta})}{||\zeta(s - \Delta r e ^{i\theta})||} : \theta \in \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}, \Delta r \rightarrow 0^{+} $$

imply that $\zeta(s) = 0$?

Comment: $\zeta$ is continuous at $s$ so if $\zeta(s)\ne 0$ both sides approach a limit and we get $\zeta(s)/|\zeta(s)|=-\zeta(s)/|\zeta(s)|$

Comment: We are very far from RH here, only the most basic properties of holomorphic functions being involved.